# How to perform a OLS regression on dynamic data frame and estimate the slope coefficient?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, regression

I have a data frame like below and it's structure is not fixed, it can have different number of column at different moment.

```
    A_Name  B_Info  Value_Yn  Value_Yn-1   Value_Yn-2   ......  Value_Y1
0   AA      X1        0.9       0.8           0.7       ......   0.1   
1   BB      Y1        0.1       0.2           0.3       ......   0.9
2   CC      Z1        -0.9       -0.8         -0.7      ......   -0.1
3   DD      L1        -0.1       -0.2         -0.3      ......   -0.9
```

I want to perform a linear regression for each row where values of X and Y are as

```
X = [n, n-1, n-2, .....2, 1]

Y = [Value_Yn, Value_Yn-1, Value_Yn-2.......Value_Y2, Value_Y1]
```

Here 'n' is number of column that will be prefixed with 'Value_'

Let's assume that n = 9

I will have value of

For Row 0

```
X = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
Y = [0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1]
```

For Row 1

```
X = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
Y = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
```

Similarly for other rows...

I want output in this format...

```
    A_Name  B_Info  Intercept  Slope_Coefficent
0   AA      X1        0         0.1  
1   BB      Y1        1         -0.1
2   CC      Z1        0         -0.1        
3   DD      L1        -1        0.1
```

Data-set is large and doing it by looping is not the correct way...

Comment: not really sure what you're asking ... maybe you want to use `multiprocessing` to do many rows in parallel?

Comment: It's just a transformation, please look at the output....I don't what multiprocessing mean here.....but I want the regression for each row..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved with numpy and linear algebra. The basic idea is that because you are reusing the same x values over and over again, we can reuse intermediate computations.

### **The derivation.**

Linear regression is usually solved like this:

1. Given a dataset (x_1, y_1) ... (x_n, y_n), we solve a least squares
   problem of the form A x = b.
2. A is a n x 2 matrix with x-values as one column, and ones in the second, the vector b contains y values, and x has the slope and intercept.
3. We multiply both sides by A transpose, obtaining A^T A x= A^T b, a 2-d system that is solvable for the slope and intercept.

Suppose your dataframe has k rows. You're trying to do least squares k times for the same x-values but different y-values. This translates to solving the underlying Least Squares problem k times with the same A and different b's.

We can exploit this in two ways. The first is to compute A^T A only once. The second, and the result of most of the speedup, is to **simultaneously** solve all k least squares problems at once using matrix multiplication.  The idea is to stick all k b's in as the columns of a matrix B. Then, replace little b with big B on the right hand side, and do all the same matrix multiplications. You'll end up with a matrix X whose columns are in correspondence with the columns of B.

Note that B is the transpose of the matrix whose columns are Y_1, Y_2, ... Y_n. So it's the transpose of your dataframe.

In other words, X = (A^T A)^(-1) A^T B, where B is the transpose of your data frame. If the math isn't clear, here's my code (using dummy data). Please let me know if  something doesn't work.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la

n = 3
k= 10
#replace this with your data matrix whose columns are the Y's
yvals = np.arange(k*n).reshape(k,n)
xvals = np.arange(1,n+1)
print "X values:", xvals
print "Y Values:"
print yvals

A = np.zeros((n,2))
A[:,0] = xvals
A[:,1] = 1

Q = A.T.dot(A)
#slopes are the first column, intercepts are the second
res =  la.inv(Q).dot(A.T.dot(yvals.T)).T
print res
```

The output:

```
X values: [1 2 3]
Y Values:
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]
 [12 13 14]
 [15 16 17]
 [18 19 20]
 [21 22 23]
 [24 25 26]
 [27 28 29]]
Result:
[[  1.  -1.]
 [  1.   2.]
 [  1.   5.]
 [  1.   8.]
 [  1.  11.]
 [  1.  14.]
 [  1.  17.]
 [  1.  20.]
 [  1.  23.]
 [  1.  26.]]
```

This should be quite fast due to vectorization and asymptotic speedups from matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thanks. This is what they teach you in an Applied Mathematics major.

Comment: Can I also get adjusted R Square.....just by doing some operations on metrics ...

Comment: Probably. You should also  probably ask a followup question, as this one is resolved. Get me the link and I'll try to answer it.